# Electricity withdrawal

Tags: nouns, science

We commonly say "electricity consumption" for both :

- the electric energy actually consumed by appliances
- the electric energy drawn from the grid by a house, measured by a meter (what appears on your utility bill)

I would like to find a more specific word for the latter, in the specific context of "measuring electric energy flow inside a house" :

- From the energy supplier's point of view, electricity drawn to your house is a consumption no matter what you do with it. The supplier calls "energy drawn from the grid" consumption because the supplier charges you for it (business).
- From within your house, you could store the drawn electric energy in a  battery rather than "consuming" it (converting the electric energy to another form). Therefore, not all energy drawn is necessarily "consumed" (physics). You can also "draw electric energy" from a solar panel, so the energy from the grid becomes just one of many "energy withdrawals".

Translations from the French word "Soutirage" (literally "under pull") include *racking* or *withdrawal* but they seem seldom used online.

What is the correct noun for the action of *drawing energy* from a source ?

Comment: You could say "load", or "electrical load"

Comment: Yep, to an electrical engineering type it's a "load".

Comment: Your energy management system is an 'appliance', and any consumption not lost to entropy can be called 'storage'.  Using it later can be called 'production', along with any local 'generation'.

Comment: Is "soutirage" akin to sucking electricity?

Comment: Soutirage comes from [brewing](https://goo.gl/images/iAo2Xo). Yes it’s kind of “sucking in” : _draining_ or _tapping_ from a barrel.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the original *electricity consumption*. (Also, both of your list items mean the same thing—as a noun. But you are confusingly mixing the verb and the noun throughout your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Wattage, power usage,* or *current drain*.

Soutirage immediately brings *sapping* to mind (as in, sapping electricity from a source is a bit like drawing from it), except that it's not a very elegant term, and probably not suitable for describing power drawn by a household.

Comment: The best noun would be electrical "usage" (as opposed to the line charge). It's on the bill, but good luck searching it on Google.

Comment: When I hear _drain_ I think about _loss_ or _waste_, like _something draining a battery_. Is it only my interpretation ? I think _usage_ is exactly what I'm searching for. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Any action is described by a verb not a noun. A verb can be used as a noun; for instance *The drawing of electricity costs money*.

The utility of electricity is described by what it accomplishes. This can be making a wheel turn or just warming a chemical process to charge a battery. Both of these are described as *Work*.